# django exception handler middleware and handler500

Tags: python, django, exception, django-views, middleware

I have a django application with `handler500` set. I want to add custom exception handler to it.
I create a middleware which handles process exception:

> Django calls process_exception() when a view raises an exception. process_exception() should return either None or an HttpResponse object. If it returns an HttpResponse object, the response will be returned to the browser. Otherwise, default exception handling kicks in.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process-exception

My `ErrorMiddleware` looks like:

```
class ErrorMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        try:
            #logic goes here
        except Exception:
            pass
        return None
```

My `settings` looks like:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'my.error.ErrorMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
DEBUG = False
```

In this case, my browser never gets a response from page with exception. Though without my middleware in the list, I get `handler500` working correctly.

I want default exception handling mechanism to be executed, without explicitly calling `handler500` view in my middleware.

**UPD**:

handler500 module looks like this:

```
#imports ....

def custom_500(request):
    """ Return an error ID (hash) that can be provided to support """
    return render(request, '500.html', {
        'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
        'diagcode': "hello",
        }
    )
```

Comment: Could you show a module with your `handler500` definition?

Answer (score 5):

Try moving your middleware to the bottom of the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` stack so it's the first piece of middleware that gets to handle the request on its way out to the client. I believe Django has already caught your exception and rendered its own error 500 page if you put it last.